# How about having a language provide both call-by-name and call-by-value?

Tags: programming-languages

Is it OK to have a language provide both call-by-need (CBN) and call-by-value (CBV) evaluation strategy? I mean without fixing it and simulating in one the other but let the user choose which when in need. For example, let the language has a `eval` function as in Scheme available which can accept one more argument from the user specifying which evaluation strategy he wants.

Comment: Although I have provide an answer, I think this question might yield more answers if migrated to stackoverflow. What do you think @plmday?

Comment: Thanks, Dave. That's a good idea.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't deliver any further results (yet).

Answer (score 6):

Combining call-by-need (laziness) and call-by-value (strictness) in one language implementation is certainly possible, as long as one takes care to avoid making computations with side effects lazy and making diverging computations strict.

[Strictness analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strictness_analysis) is used in lazy (CBN) functional languages to detect when functions can safely be evaluated using a CBV strategy. CBV evaluation is generally faster, but using this evaluation strategy for non-strict functions changes the semantics of the program.

[Wadler](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/papers/lazyinstrict/lazyinstrict.ps) describes how to combine lazy and strict computation in a functional language.

A lambda the ultimate [thread](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/243) also addresses the issue.

[Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) has a keyword `lazy` for stating that certain computations are to be performed lazily. Other languages have similar constructs.